Power BI Gateway Schedule Refresh is not able to use
Schedule refresh option is not working/Hide/Disabled in Power Bi Service
I have tried to publish a report in a newly created workspace, for that i have checked the status of gateway i.e. Online, then in our report semantic model there are multiple settings options.  Semantic model description, Gateway and cloud connection, Data source credentials and Refresh and many more. But Data source credentials and Refresh is not working its like disabled.
